# Octave function should return a vector, not an 'ans'

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to understand how values are returned in Octave functions. I wrote a function which returns more than one variable, which is `[error, accuracy, precision, npv, recall, F1_score]`.

What I'm trying achieve is to **return every** **result variable** to console instead of **standard `ans`** (which seems to be always the first variable).

So this works fine:

```
>> [error, accuracy, precision, npv, recall, F1_score] = describeConfMatrix([546, 0;314, 0])
error =  0.36512
accuracy =  0.63488
precision =  0.63488
npv = NA
recall =  1
F1_score =  0.77667
```

But this produces 'ans':

```
>> z = describeConfMatrix([546, 0;314, 0])
z =  0.36512
>> describeConfMatrix([546, 0;314, 0])
ans =  0.36512
```

while I expect to see whole list of return variables as well.

I also want to get this working (assertions for testing the function):

```
m = [546, 0;314, 0];
ans = [0.36512, 0.63488, 0.63488, NA, 1, 0.77667];
assert(isequal(describeConfMatrix(m),ans))
```

Many thanks from a Matlab newbie !

This is my code:

```
function [error, accuracy, precision, npv, recall, F1_score] = describeConfMatrix(m)
  TP = m(1,1);
  FN = m(1,2);
  FP = m(2,1);
  TN = m(2,2);
  K = TP + FN + FP + TN;
  error = (FP + FN) / K;
  accuracy = (TP + TN) / K;
  precision = TP / (TP + FP); # sometimes called 'positive predictive value'
  recall = TP / (TP + FN);
  if (FN + TN) != 0
    npv = TN / (FN + TN);
  else
    npv = NA;
  end;
  F1_score = (2*precision*recall)/(precision + recall);
end
```

Comment: MATLAB will not return the list of variables either because there is no robust way for it to know how to name them to prevent overwriting data. This is why it returns only the first answer as `ans` when no outputs are specified. In order to ensure it returns all data with no output variables specified you will need to utilize [`varargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) or format your output into a single array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- If you do not specify an output argument to your function call (e.g. `describeConfMatrix([546, 0;314, 0])`), it will return the first output variable only as `ans`.
- If you specify just one variable, it will also return the first output variable (`z = describeConfMatrix([546, 0;314, 0])`).
- If you want all the variables to be returned, you have to specify them in your function call, as in  `[error, accuracy, precision, npv, recall, F1_score] = describeConfMatrix([546, 0;314, 0])`

That is normal and expected behaviour in MATLAB/Octave. Your `assert` line won't work for the same reasons.